# How do I create and validate a signature using the EventStreamAws4Signer class from the SNS Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to figure out how to use the EventStreamAws4Signer class from the SNS SDK for java to create signatures and validate them. I've asked ChatGPT to give me a code example and it came up with the following code:

```
public void publishMessage(String topicArn, String message) {
    SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

    PublishRequest publishRequest = PublishRequest.builder()
            .topicArn(topicArn)
            .message(message)
            .build();

    EventStreamAws4Signer signer = EventStreamAws4Signer.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

    SdkBytes payload = SdkBytes.fromByteArray(message.getBytes());

    String signature = signer.sign(publishRequest, payload).get("signature");

    snsClient.publish(builder -> builder
            .message(message)
            .topicArn(topicArn)
            .signature(signature)
            .build());
}
```

The problem with this code is that in reality `EventStreamAws4Signer` doesn't have a `builder()` method. It only has a `create()` method. But this method doesn't let you configure the object. I need to be able to make a signature using the credentials of an IAM user or the temporary credentials of an instance profile role.

I've already checked the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/java_sns_code_examples.html) and [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/sns/src/main/java/com/example/sns) to see if I could find any examples on how to do this. But I couldn't find what i was looking for.

So my question is: How do i create and validate signatures using the `EventStreamAws4Signer` from AWS SNS Sdk (v1) for java?